# My website is running slow, I dont know why?

Tags: php, javascript, linux, apache

I'm currently building a website as a project for school and I'm pretty new to php, js etc...

The website is geekwiz.com, It runs really slow and I don't know why.

I used http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ tools to see why but it just says wait is 25s.

If anyone knows how to help that'be awesome.

Regards,
Otc

Comment: Hi Julien and welcome to StackOverflow.  This question is very open ended and doesn;t really have enough info for anyone to help you. Please find a specific problem then many people will help tell you how you can work around it.

Comment: Your question is very vague, there could be a myriad of reasons why it's slow. Try at least working with [page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions), and take it from there. Once you rule out design, you can start looking at actual code, network/server issues, etc.

Comment: geekwiz.com 346k page = very fat http://analyze.websiteoptimization.com/authenticate.php?url=geekwiz.com&

Comment: Next time, consider better technologies like http://ocsigen.org/ or http://opalang.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It might be because you have done some very wrong SQL queries.
- It might be because you have made very bad data-base design.
- It might be because you have some kind of loop going on.
- Probably it's because you are hosting it on very bad and cheap
  hosting provider, like GoDaddy for example.

Comment: You shouldn't dignify questions like these with a result - SO is about specific, answerable questions, not *it's broke. help*.

Comment: I agree that it is most likely something on the server side (so the js is irrelevant)

Comment: @Lattyware Nevermind that. Reputation points are at stake! But seriously.. you answer isn't even specific enough to be considered a good answer. I could rattle off another 20 things it MIGHT be.